# How to implement DoDirectPayment in paypal using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am newbie to paypal. I want to implement direct payment api for my website. Means i will be having a buy button when i click on that it will expand and in that iframe i will be having the url for paypal direct payment. I have written the code like

```
     string address = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=user&COUNTRYCODE=US&ZIP=95131&STATE=CA&CITY=San Jose&FIRSTNAME=John&LASTNAME=Smith&STREET=1asfasdfSt&CVV2=123&ACCT=4683075410516684&IPADDRESS=192.168.0.62&PWD=1357635822&EXPDATE=042011&VERSION=58.0&SIGNATURE=signature&METHOD=DoDirectPayment&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&AMT=10.00&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&RETURNURL=http://returnurl&CANCELURL=http://cancnelurl";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string req = rdr.ReadToEnd();
```

But the `req` contains the failure message. I don't know what credentials i am missing.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the error message say?  Also you might need to URL encode the parameters on the query string

Comment: The response contains `TIMESTAMP=2013%2d02%2d28T13%3a05%3a22Z&CORRELATIONID=ddda63e952b88&ACK=Failure&VERSION=58%2e0&BUILD=5294323&L_ERRORCODE0=10562&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Invalid%20Data&L_LONGMESSAGE0=This%20transaction%20cannot%20be%20processed%2e%20Please%20enter%20a%20valid%20credit%20card%20expiration%20year%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error&AMT=10%2e00&CURRENCYCODE=USD`

Comment: when i encode the url it is getting an exception Invalid Uri

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that its the expiry date thats the problem.

You are passing EXPDATE=042011 which looks to me like a date in the past.

Edit:

10500 Invalid Configuration This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
Occurs when you have not agreed to the billing agreement.

10501 Invalid Configuration This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.

Occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive.

Comment: I have changed the date to future but no success

Comment: Invalid merchant configuration i will looking forward to that

Comment: I have given the same sandbox credentials. But it is getting the same error. The same credentials has worked for SetExpressCheckout.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your account, it might be worth contacting them to make sure it is set up for this function call.

Comment: But the same credentials have been working for SetExpressCheckout method

Comment: Agree to the billing agreement?

Comment: Failing that, contact them and ask what is wrong on your account

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned, the error that you are getting is because pro is not enabled on the account you are using the credentials for.  Express Checkout does not require any special billing agreement, this is why your Express Checkout calls were working.

I have enabled to pro service on your test sandbox account, and you should be able to test with it now.

Comment: Yah thank you. Actually my requirement is direct payment in same website with out redirecting to the paypal page. What should i add to my code to get that functionality. Sorry for my language.

Comment: You would need to create a interface for your buyers to enter in the billing information.  Then have it post the data over to your page that executtes the DoDirectPayment API call, and then parse out the response.  Checkout out the PayPal SDK's for a working example, and the code is already there for the buyer interface.

Comment: Is there any template for the html page. Where can i find the template

Comment: The only example would be the one from the SDK.  I have provided the code for that page below as another answer, since the comment section limits you to only so many characters.  Keep in mind that you will need to modify some of the code, and remove the code that generates the credit card number for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PayPal Merchant SDK - DoDirectPayment API</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Common/sdk.css"/>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function generateCC(){
        var cc_number = new Array(16);
        var cc_len = 16;
        var start = 0;
        var rand_number = Math.random();

        switch(document.DoDirectPaymentForm.creditCardType.value)
        {
            case "Visa":
                cc_number[start++] = 4;
                break;
            case "Discover":
                cc_number[start++] = 6;
                cc_number[start++] = 0;
                cc_number[start++] = 1;
                cc_number[start++] = 1;
                break;
            case "MasterCard":
                cc_number[start++] = 5;
                cc_number[start++] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
                break;
            case "Amex":
                cc_number[start++] = 3;
                cc_number[start++] = Math.round(Math.random()) ? 7 : 4 ;
                cc_len = 15;
                break;
        }

        for (var i = start; i < (cc_len - 1); i++) {
            cc_number[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        }

        var sum = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < (cc_len - 1); j++) {
            var digit = cc_number[j];
            if ((j & 1) == (cc_len & 1)) digit *= 2;
            if (digit > 9) digit -= 9;
            sum += digit;
        }

        var check_digit = new Array(0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
        cc_number[cc_len - 1] = check_digit[sum % 10];

        document.DoDirectPaymentForm.creditCardNumber.value = "";
        for (var k = 0; k < cc_len; k++) {
            document.DoDirectPaymentForm.creditCardNumber.value += cc_number[k];
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h3>DoDirectPayment</h3>
            <div id="apidetails">Process a credit card payment.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="request_form">     
            <form method="POST" action="DoDirectPayment.php"
                name="DoDirectPaymentForm">
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Payment type</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <select name="paymentType">
                            <option value="Sale" selected="selected">Sale</option>
                            <option value="Authorization">Authorization</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">First name</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="John"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Last name</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="Doe"/>
                    </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Card type</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <select name="creditCardType"
                            onChange="javascript:generateCC(); return false;">
                                <option value="Visa" selected="selected">Visa</option>
                                <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
                                <option value="Discover">Discover</option>
                                <option value="Amex">American Express</option>
                        </select>               
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Card number</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="19" maxlength="19" name="creditCardNumber">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Expiry date</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <select name="expDateMonth">
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="expDateYear">                 
                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                            <option value="2014" selected>2014</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>                      
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">CVV</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="4" name="cvv2Number" value="962">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Amount</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                         <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="7" name="amount" value="1.00"> USD
                    </div>
                </div>              
                <div class="section_header">Billing address</div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Address 1</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="100" name="address1" value="1 Main St">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Address 2 (optional)</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="100" name="address2" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">City</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="40" name="city" value="San Jose">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">State</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <select id=state name="state">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="AK">AK</option>
                            <option value="AL">AL</option>
                            <option value="AR">AR</option>
                            <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                            <option value="CA" selected>CA</option>
                            <option value="CO">CO</option>
                            <option value="CT">CT</option>
                            <option value="DC">DC</option>
                            <option value="DE">DE</option>
                            <option value="FL">FL</option>
                            <option value="GA">GA</option>
                            <option value="HI">HI</option>
                            <option value="IA">IA</option>
                            <option value="ID">ID</option>
                            <option value="IL">IL</option>
                            <option value="IN">IN</option>
                            <option value="KS">KS</option>
                            <option value="KY">KY</option>
                            <option value="LA">LA</option>
                            <option value="MA">MA</option>
                            <option value="MD">MD</option>
                            <option value="ME">ME</option>
                            <option value="MI">MI</option>
                            <option value="MN">MN</option>
                            <option value="MO">MO</option>
                            <option value="MS">MS</option>
                            <option value="MT">MT</option>
                            <option value="NC">NC</option>
                            <option value="ND">ND</option>
                            <option value="NE">NE</option>
                            <option value="NH">NH</option>
                            <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                            <option value="NM">NM</option>
                            <option value="NV">NV</option>
                            <option value="NY">NY</option>
                            <option value="OH">OH</option>
                            <option value="OK">OK</option>
                            <option value="OR">OR</option>
                            <option value="PA">PA</option>
                            <option value="RI">RI</option>
                            <option value="SC">SC</option>
                            <option value="SD">SD</option>
                            <option value="TN">TN</option>
                            <option value="TX">TX</option>
                            <option value="UT">UT</option>
                            <option value="VA">VA</option>
                            <option value="VT">VT</option>
                            <option value="WA">WA</option>
                            <option value="WI">WI</option>
                            <option value="WV">WV</option>
                            <option value="WY">WY</option>
                            <option value="AA">AA</option>
                            <option value="AE">AE</option>
                            <option value="AP">AP</option>
                            <option value="AS">AS</option>
                            <option value="FM">FM</option>
                            <option value="GU">GU</option>
                            <option value="MH">MH</option>
                            <option value="MP">MP</option>
                            <option value="PR">PR</option>
                            <option value="PW">PW</option>
                            <option value="VI">VI</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Zip code</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="zip" value="95131"> (5 or 9 digits)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Country</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="country" value="US">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">Phone</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="phone" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name">IPN listener URL</div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                        <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="200" name="notifyURL" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="params">
                    <div class="param_name"></div>
                    <div class="param_value">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="DoDirectPaymentBtn"
                        value="DoDirectPayment" />
                </div>                          
            </form>
            <a href="../index.php">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        generateCC();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```